# Can't connect MySQL locally through MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I followed https://flaviocopes.com/mysql-how-to-install/ to install MySQL on my MacBook running Big Sur.

I'm attempting to create a new connection and I click the button labelled "Configure Server Management" and before I can complete the installation I'm met with the following error:

```
Check if ~/sandboxes/msb_|Enter version here|/my.sandbox.cnf can be accessed
Operation failed: File ~/sandboxes/msb_|Enter version here|/my.sandbox.cnf doesn't exist
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRaLx.jpg

Couldn't find a solve for this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS MySQL doesn't use a configuration file by default. It runs with default values. So, for the connection setup part you can just ignore the error and skip over that page.

You can later create a config file in the admin section of your connection and once that has been stored update the management section in the connections editor with the correct path.

[image]